# Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher vs. Application.Current.Dispatcher

Tags: .net, wpf, dispatcher

What are the differences between `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` (in `System.Windows.Threading`) and `Application.Current.Dispatcher` (in `System.Windows`)?

My gut tells me that `Application.Current.Dispatcher` will never change and is global to all threads in the current application, while `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` may create a new instance of `Dispatcher` depending on the thread from which it was called.

Is that correct?

If it is, is the purpose of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` primarily for multi-threaded UI?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> My gut tells me that Application.Current.Dispatcher will never change
>   and is global to all threads in the current application, while
>   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher may create a new instance of Dispatcher
>   depending on the thread from which it was called.

That is correct.

Additionally, there is no point whatsoever in accessing `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from a non-UI thread. It will do nothing unless you call [`Dispatcher.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run.aspx), and going into an infinite message loop is not what you want to be doing from within worker threads.

So:

- **In the most common scenario**, where your app only has a single UI thread, `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from within the UI thread will return the same instance. Which one you use is simply a matter of preference.
- If your app has more than one UI thread then each [`DispatcherObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.aspx) will be 
  permanently associated with the dispatcher of the UI thread it was created in upon construction. In this case, `Application.Current.Dispatcher` will refer to the dispatcher of the thread your application spawned with; you will not be able to use it to post messages to controls owned by your other UI threads.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what do you mean by "It will do nothing unless you call Dispatcher.Run"? I've used CurrentDispatcher from a non-UI thread, and Invoke does indeed invoke a delegate. Do you mean that the delegates will simply be invoked on the calling thread?

Comment: @ken: `Invoke` and friends normally "package" (marshal, if you prefer) a method call into a Win32 message and post it to a message queue from which a message loop (the dispatcher loop) eventually extracts it and executes the call. Since there is no dispatcher loop (if you were in that loop *your* code would not be running) the call would never actually happen. So I assume that `Invoke` first checks if you are already in the `CurrentDispatcher` thread as an optimization and if you are executes the call on the spot instead of marshalling. You can verify this by checking `Thread.ManagedThreadId`.

Comment: *you will not be able to use it to post messages to controls owned by your other UI threads.*  So, how many UI threads are there in your average WPF application?

Comment: @Will: One: *"If your app only has one UI thread (most likely)..."*. Do you think it needs more clarification?

Comment: @Jon: Well, considering it confused me, yeah.  I didn't see the line you quoted...

Comment: @Will: Edited to increase visibility of the relevant part. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 28):

To put it simply...

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` gets the dispatcher *for the current thread*.  So, if you're looking for the UI thread's Dispatcher from a background process, don't use this.

`Application.Current.Dispatcher` will always give you the UI thread's dispatcher, as this is the thread that spins up the sole Application instance.

Answer (score 10):

> My gut tells me that Application.Current.Dispatcher will never change and is global to all threads in the current application, while Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher may create a new instance of Dispatcher depending on the thread from which it was called.

That is correct, the `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is an instance  property of the application which is assigned upon construction to be the dispatcher of the current thread. And as the documentation of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` points out:

> Gets the Dispatcher for the thread currently executing and creates a new Dispatcher if one is not already associated with the thread.

---

> If it is, is the purpose of Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher primarily for multi-threaded UI?

Possibly, i have not encountered any use in getting the dispatcher of a background thread as you usually have no UI-elments belonging to them to which you may want to dispatch operations.