# Cross-Thread operation not valid exception occured, even when I am using ThreadSafe call

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Following is the code for my ThreadSafe function

```
public static void ThreadSafe(Action action)
        {
             System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
             new MethodInvoker(action));
        }
```

I am using this `ThreadSafe` function to access various cross-thread actions. Its working fine in other classes but when I am adding a user control `Comment` in panel `commentContainer`, its showing following error.

> Cross-thread operation not valid exception

Following its screenshot with the code:
[image]

I want to pass the `comment` string to this control. The control processing is based on this value.
I think my way of using this function is wrong. Can any one please improve my code if its not correct? And if correct then please tell me what to do to solve this issue?

Also note that when I removed the `foreach` loop, the background worker is working fine.

`setTopicInfo()` code:

```
public void setTopicInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                TopicInfo.Text = "Topic Views: " + dops.getVisiteds(tid) + " | " +
                    "People Involved: " + dops.getPeopleInvolved(tid) + " | ";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { TopicInfo.Text = "[Some error occured while loading Topic Information. Please reopen or refresh this topic.] | "; }
        }
```

Comment: You may consider using the existing `Control.Invoke` method.

Comment: can you tell me how to use it in my code's case? Can you convert my code using `Control.Invoke`?

Comment: I believe it would be `commentContainer.Invoke(new Action(() => addComment(comment)))` instead of `Main.ThreadSafe...`.

Comment: thanks @Ginosaji, it worked. Write it in answer so that I can mark it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` returns a `Dispatcher` for the current thread. In this example, the `ThreadSafe` method was invoking the `Action` on the current thread rather than on the thread that created `commentContainer` (usually referred to as the UI thread.)

WinForms facilitates invoking code on the UI thread through the `Control.Invoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke` methods. A quick one-line fix to this example is replacing the call to `Main.ThreadSafe` with a call to `commentContainer.Invoke` or `commentContainer.BeginInvoke`. You may also take advantage of the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event, as suggest by Bill Sambrone.

Answer (score 1):

Your ThreadSafe method establishes a Dispatcher while it is called from a bgw thread.

And this is what MSDN has to say about `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` :

> If a Dispatcher is not associated with the current thread, a new Dispatcher will be created.

Use Application.Dispatcher instead. See for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher).

Comment: The question is about WinForms, so `Application.Current` will probably be null. (I'm assuming you meant `Application.Current.Dispatcher` as in that other question.)

Comment: Dispatcher and Current doesn't exits in Application Class.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the WinForms tag. Still, same problem, other solution.

Comment: @ShivaPareek That's probably because you're looking at `System.Windows.Forms.Application` rather than `System.Windows.Application`. (But like I said, if you did use `System.Windows.Application`, that probably still wouldn't help you. Go with Ginosaji's comments on your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a BackgroundWorker, you can set the comment using its ability to report progress. Either create the ReportProgress event handler through the designer or add it in code if you are creating your BWWorker from code. Make sure you enable the flag for ReportsProgress.

Then, in your foreach loop:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(yourdatagoeshere)
```

In the backgroundWorker1_ReportsProgress method, you would then pass that data to your addComment method.