# Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke Not Invoking

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` and the events raised by this when a watched file changes are raised on a different thread from the UI thread. To avoid and cross-thread acess volation fun, I am attempting to use

```
public void RaisePathChanged(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        // Some code to handle the file state change here.
    }));
}
```

This compiles fine and the `RaisePathChanged` is fired as it should be. However, the code inside the delegate `Action(() => { /*Here*/ })` never gets called/invoked, the code is merely skipped.

**Why is the code being skipped, how can I fix it and is this the best way to insure code is run on the thread that created it in WPF?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are mixing up things.

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is not the same as `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

The second one is the one you seem to be looking for.

Take a look at this.

[Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher vs. Application.Current.Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher)

Try it out with application dispatcher.

Answer (score 5):

`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is the dispatcher of the "current" thread - in this case the thread `RaisePathChanged` is executing on.
When you say `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` .NET will create a new dispatcher if there was none. 
It will however not `Run()` said dispatcher!
So when you schedule something on it (with `BeginInvoke`) it will not actually be executed unless that dispatcher is running.
That likely answers your first question (Why is it not Invoking?)
To avoid cross-thread access violation, you need the dispatcher of the thread that created whatever you are trying to protect and make sure it is a running dispatcher.
If whatever you are trying to protect was created on the default GUI thread, then use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` like the previous answer says, otherwise you will need to do a bit more explaining and post a bit more code before we can answer your second question. http://www.diranieh.com/NET_WPF/Threading.htm has a pretty short intro into the subject.