# Why do I get 'The calling thread must be STA' exception although invoking via Dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, sta

This method call sits inside a class derived from `DispatcherObject`:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                var exported = formatProvider.Export(original.Workbook);
                Workbook = formatProvider.Import(exported);
            }));
```

The method on the class is called by a backgroundworker in its `DoWork` delegate.

Workbook is *Telerik's* Workbook, as used by the RadSpreadsheetControl. Obviously, workbooks can only be accessed by the UI thread.

The above code throws an `InvalidOperationException`, saying

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

I don't really understand, as I thought that when invoking the actions with a Dispatcher, I would be calling it from the UI Thread, which is STA?

What am I missing here and how can this be fixed? Or should this work in general and the bug is somewhere else? What could be a reason then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: You must create this `DispatcherObject` inside your UI thread, not in a worker.

[`DispatcherObject.Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which you are marshalling the operation to, is set to [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the time of the object's construction. If the object is not created inside your existing UI thread then the documented behavior of `CurrentDispatcher` is to create a new dispatcher object associated with the thread. Later on, `Invoke` tries to marshal the call to that thread (which is not STA) resulting in the error.

Comment: Ok, get it. What is a good practice to access the GUI thread in an object which hasn't been created by the main GUI thread? Can I - for instance - expose an application wide DispatcherObject which has been created in the GUI thread in a static field with a lock or something like that?? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Marc: `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is such a static helper, most of the time it will work fine.

Comment: @Marc: There's a related answer of mine here, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10448987/50079

Answer (score 3):

It is not sufficient to use a class derived from `DispatcherObject`. You must use the `Dispatcher` from an existing `UIElement` created from XAML (or at least make sure, you create your class from inside the GUI thread where it picks the right `Dispatcher`).

Comment: `UIElement` *is* a `DispatcherObject`, so the first sentence is really meaningless. The second sentence is also made equivalent to "use another object's dispatcher instead", in which case why make the current object a `DispatcherObject` to begin with?

Comment: Well - I edited that first part to make clearer what I meant. The second part is alternative, for when the OP doesn't have access to any existing UIElement where `Dispatcher.Invoke` is needed.