# Non-UI "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following code:

```
var queue = printer.PrintQueue;
var canPrint = ! Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(()
                            => queue.IsPaperJammed || queue.IsOutOfPaper || 
                               queue.IsInError || queue.HasPaperProblem);
```

It is throwing the following error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

I have tried this on UI thread (using the dispatcher as shown above) and I have tried it on the current thread (without the dispatcher).

**Is there a way to ask a object which thread owns it?**

Comment: There is a way to determine if a Dispatcher.Invoke is required. Would that answer your question?

Comment: @LordTakkera -  I am not sure it would, because I try it with the Dispatcher and with out and it fails both times with the same error.  My guess is that there is a different owning thread out there.

Comment: What is creating `printer`? I don't think you can easily figure out which thread owns an object, but perhaps we can figure out which one is.

Comment: I believe your call to the dispatcher launches a thread.  (Therefore the thread trying to USE your queue is a different thread than the one that CREATED it.)  I would suggest either moving the CREATING of the queue to being inside of the invoke the thread OR move the test for error conditions to BEFORE the invoke.  A bigger sample of what you are trying to do may help.  (The small sample gives no indication why multi-threading would even be called for in this case.)

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. The real problem lies on why are you trying to access an object that was created from a different Dispatcher into another different Dispatcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried without `CurrentDispatcher` ? :

```
var canPrint = ! Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()
                            => queue.IsPaperJammed || queue.IsOutOfPaper || 
                               queue.IsInError || queue.HasPaperProblem);
```

`CurrentDispatcher.Invoke()` will invoke your code from the thread currently executing, it is non-UI thread assuming that snippet in this question is run from non-UI thread.

References :

- [Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher vs. Application.Current.Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher)
- [Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to determine if the CURRENT thread owns a control: 
Use `control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` to check whether the current thread owns the control. If it does not own it then `Invoke` an `Action` using dispatcher.

Comment: `System.Printing.PrintQueue` does not have a Disptacher member (that I could find).

Answer (score 0):

just crazy as it is, the following code did not work, and it still throws the exception

```
dlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(302.36220472, int.MaxValue);
dlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
```

but this code worked

```
dlg.PrintTicket = new PrintTicket()
{
    PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(273, int.MaxValue),
    PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait,
};
```

of course the both code must be in `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {})` but still the first will throw the exception and the second will solve the problem