# WPF UI update from a timer thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, dispatcher

Within the App I display banners that rotate as time progresses or when user clicks next/previous.

1) I need to update an UI element within `Timer.Elapsed` method. From what I found, it seems that timer ticks are executed on their own thread and element's dispatcher should be use to update the UI.

```
( (Image)BannerPanel.Content ).Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( () => {
    ( (Image)BannerPanel.Content ).Source = GetImage( new Uri( banner.Uri, UriKind.Absolute ) );
} ) );
```

but that throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

2) The banner controller provides `Next` and `Previous` methods, which, when called display next/previous banner respectively. As `DisplayBanner` method tries to display banner and when the file is not found it tries to re-download it using `WebClient`'s `AsyncFileDownload` and on `DownloadComplete` it displays the image. Am I correct to assume that both, `Elapsed` fired by the timer and manual call of `Next`/`Previous` can occure at the same time, both being run on their own thread ( `Previous`/`Next` on UI thread and `Elapsed` on Timer thread ), possibly causing instability?

Comment: Just use a `DispatcherTimer` instead of a `Timer`.

Comment: There is a `Dispatcher` for *every* thread, so you might not be using the one from the UI thread. To ensure that you are, you can use the `Application.Current.Dispatcher` object. Also see [Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher vs. Application.Current.Dispatcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher) for more information. However, the `DispatcherTimer` is the correct tool for this job as it avoids any need to use the `Dispatcher` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using the `DispatcherTimer` class instead of a regular `Timer`. It's designed to be used with WPF UI for just these types of uses because it runs on the `Dispatcher` thread.

More info: [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Alright, yet do you know what's the issue with the dispatcher call I was trying to do? Just for reference.

Comment: @pikausp, see my comment on your question for that answer. This is currently the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Application instead,

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
    ((Image)BannerPanel.Content).Source = GetImage(new Uri(banner.Uri, UriKind.Absolute));
});
```

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore, but I switched to using DispatcherTimer as recommended by others.

Comment: @pikausp, yeah, DispatcherTimer is more topical when it comes to your situation. Though, this is another alternative. I would recommend using Application.Current whenever you want to do an Invoke or BeginInvoke.