# "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." when adding ListView items dynamically using BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, listview

I am trying to call a method from `BackgroundWorker` that adds a user control to `ListView`:

```
private void AddItems(List<FileItem> fileItems) {
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => files.ItemsSource = fileItems));
}
```

The user control `files` is getting the data from `fileItems` successfully in its constructor but it's throwing `The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.` exception. I already tried adding `[STAThread]` attribute to all parent methods one by one but still it's throwing the exception. Where should I add this attribute?

**UPDATE**

Please also note that `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => files.Items.Clear()));` is executing correctly.

Comment: You cannot call SetApartmentState() when the thread is already started.  You cannot arbitrarily apply [STAThread], it only works on the Main() entrypoint.  Use the proper dispatcher, Application.Current.Dispatcher probably.  You are suppose to use BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress or RunWorkerCompleted instead.

Comment: @HansPassant please see my update. And I tried your way as I mentioned in comment to answer by user2864740. But its again throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

This `Dispatcher` refers to one associated with the BGW thread, not the WPF/UI thread. By default a new dispatcher/context will be created if none is associated with the current thread; in context this is entirely useless.

If supplying the dispatcher instance ([Dispatcher.CurrentInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)) *from the UI thread that starts the BGW* then it 'ought to work'. Likewise, as Hans points out, the correct (WPF/UI) dispatcher object should be accessible through [the dispatcher associated with the Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher).

Additionally [an arbitrary object can be supplied in the ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) method; this allows sending information back to the parent. The processing of the UI components can then done in the event handler which is automatically run on the correct WPF/UI thread. (The same holds for ['work complete'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) processing.)

There is no need to set any STA threading options/attributes for a standard WPF project.

Comment: I did like this `worker.ReportProgress(90, fileItems);` and enabled `WorkerReportsProgress=true`. Also, called `files.ItemsSource = fileItems` in the `ProgressChanged` event. But still its not working. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: "Not working" = ? (In any case it should probably be done at worker-complete, if setting all the items, vs. doing an incremental change which represents 'progress'.)

Comment: Apologies for not being specific. But I meant that its still showing the same exception.

Comment: That is .. odd. No idea then. One thing to try might be to force materialization of the source if it is a enumerable, eg. `worker.ReportProgress(90, fileItems.ToList())` (although since it's not really 'progress' this would be best to return as the BGW's result and handle in the work complete handler..)

Answer (score 0):

Call BiginInvoke directly on your list view control as follows:

```
files.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => files.ItemsSource = fileItems));
```