# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke never execute action?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, dispatcher

I have that code where my action is never executed:

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 5000, 5000);
private static DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperationPrevious = null;
private static void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = 
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Debug.Print("Pass here at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("O"));
    }));

    dispatcherOperationPrevious = dispatcherOperation;
}
```

I have no debug traces about "Pass here...".

If I look at the result of BeginInvoke which is dispatcherOperation, I get (either for current or previous dispatcherOperation):

```
dispatcherOperation.Status = Pending
dispatcherOperation.Task.Status = WaitingForActivation

_dispatcherOperationPrevious .Status = Pending
_dispatcherOperationPrevious .Task.Status = WaitingForActivation
```

Why "Debug.Print..." is never executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that the TimeCallback is called on another thread. When you call Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher on a thread that doesn't have a Dispatcher, it will create a new one. (A Dispatcher is bound to a thread.)

So, you're creating a new dispatcher, but this new dispatcher is never `Run()` and your Action will be queued on a non running dispatcher.

**I think you want to call the Action on the GUI dispatcher.**

Every WPF control is dirived from `DispatcherObject` and will contain a property `Dispatcher` containing the dispatcher on where they are made on. Use that one.

So `Dispatcher.Invoke` could be interpreted as a static method call, but it is actually the a method call of the Dispatcher instance stored in the controls property Dispatcher.

Fix:

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 5000, 5000);
private static DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperationPrevious = null;
private static void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = 

    // Dispatcher here is using the controls dispatcher, the BeginInvoke is not a static method.. (like you probably assumed..
    // So calling the BeginInvoke of the controls property 'Dispatcher'
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Debug.Print("Pass here at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("O"));
    }));

    dispatcherOperationPrevious = dispatcherOperation;
}
```

If the Dispatcher property is not avaiable within the TimeCallback, for example if you created the time within some classes deep in you business layer *(bad practice)*, you can call `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to get the 'main/gui' Dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks a lots. Clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher), `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` will get the `Dispatcher` from the current thread, which in your case, is the thread of the `Timer`. If you want to invoke your debug call from the GUI thread, you need to use `Application.CurrentDispatcher` instead.

```
private static void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = 
        Application.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Debug.Print("Pass here at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("O"));
    }));

    dispatcherOperationPrevious = dispatcherOperation;
}
```

Though, instead of using a standard `Timer`, I would **recommend** using a `DispatcherTimer` . The `DispatcherTimer` is designed to be used when updating the UI (no need to explicitly invoke).

> If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth
>   noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread then
>   the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user
>   interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the
>   Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread using Invoke or
>   BeginInvoke. Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a
>   System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same
>   thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the
>   DispatcherTimer.

Comment: I received 2 excellent answers. I had to choose one. I picked up random. I upvoted yours. Thanks a lots. It is very clear.