# WPF dispatcher never executes action when running UI tests

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have a ViewModel that internally uses a `Dispatcher` to update an `ObservableCollection` asynchronously. I would like to write an unit test for that ViewModel, *including* the method that uses the Dispatcher.

I have abstracted the dispatcher using a custom `IDispatcher` injected at runtime.

Here is the `IDispatcher` implementation that I use when the app runs in normal mode

```
public class WPFDispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel uses the `IDispatcher` like so

```
public async Task RefreshControls()
{
    Parent.IsSoftBusy = true;
    if (ControlsList == null)
        ControlsList = new ObservableCollection<DataprepControl>();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var updatedControls = _getControls();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _handleUpdatedControl(updatedControls));
    });
    Parent.IsSoftBusy = false;
}
```

When switching to an execution from an unit test (Visual Studio Unit Test Framework), System.Windows.Application` might be null so I [manually instantiate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902961/7540393) at unit test startup

```
new System.Windows.Application();
```

When doing that, `Actions` passed to `Invoke` are **never executed**, they hang indefinitely.

If I add a breakpoint on the `Invoke` call, I see the `Dispatcher.Thread` is

- In STA mode (so it CAN handle GUI updates)
- Is alive (`IsAlive == true`)
- Is in the state `Background | WaitSleepJoin` (I don't know what that means, but it might be useful)

I do not understand why the actions are not being queued.

Remember that I am in a unit-test context, with no controls, so I cannot [directly call the dispatcher and set a timer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217259/dispatcher-begininvoke-never-execute-action)

[Adding a static class that somehow tells the Dispatcher to consume its tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513399/7540393) has no effect

Changing to `BeginInvoke` does not solve the issue.

Comment: If you inject an `IDispatcher` at runtime, why don't you just inject a special `IDispatcher` for unit tests which executes the action directly? Isn't that the whole point of injecting the `IDispatcher` rather than calling WPF's Dispatcher directly?

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. However, no matter what "special-IDispatcher" implementation I come up with, it systematically halts on the `Invoke`. I forgot to mention also that [adding a static class that somehow tells the Dispatcher to consume its tasks has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513399/7540393).

Comment: Besides, what do you have in mind when saying "A special `IDispatcher`" ? If I mock it with a class that only executes the action on the current Thread, the ObservableCollection will still complain that it cannot be edited outside of the Thread that has initialized it.

Comment: Ah, OK, then I'll remove the duplicate.

Comment: *"the ObservableCollection will still complain that it cannot be edited outside of the Thread that has initialized it."* Good point. I'm afraid, I don't have a solution then, just a few things to try: What happens if you replace the dispatcher call with a task continuation with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()? That should capture the context in which the ObservableCollection was created and execute the continuation in the same context.

Comment: @Heinzi I'm not sure what you mean by that suggestion. Should `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` have a method `ContinueWith` that I'm missing ?

Comment: Okay, I gave it a spin and it still returns that [I cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331723/this-type-of-collectionview-does-not-support-changes-to-its-sourcecollection-fro).

Comment: I see. Thanks for trying, and sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the view model method is called in the UI thread of your application, the following code modification should eliminate the need for using a Dispatcher:

```
public async Task RefreshControls()
{
    Parent.IsSoftBusy = true;

    if (ControlsList == null)
    {
        ControlsList = new ObservableCollection<DataprepControl>();
    }

    var updatedControls = await Task.Run(() => _getControls());

    _handleUpdatedControl(updatedControls);

    Parent.IsSoftBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: I can validate that moving the instruction that touches the ObservableCollection _outside_ of `Task.Run` did the trick. Now this will require some rework on my end because `_handleUpdatedControls` is super heavy and needs to be ran asynchronously. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: But Dispatcher.Invoke would also have called it in the UI thread. It shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: This is true. I don't know what I had in mind. I just realized this whole question was a misuse of `Dispatcher.Invoke` inside a `Thread.Run` which, as you said, should theoretically not make any difference, but hangs when executed in a unit test.

Comment: Correction, I remember why I did that. I did not know that `Task.Run` could return a concrete result. I thought it was something awaitable but with some built-in restrictions. So I thought I couldn't run `__getControls` asynchronously AND do something with its result synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer stated, it's always best to use `await` for updating the UI with results of a background operation, or if you need multiple updates, use `IProgress<T>`.

There are some scenarios where this isn't possible, though, such as external factors needing to update your UI. In this case you have some update coming in on a background thread and you do need to queue an update to the UI.

In this scenario, I generally recommend wrapping `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Dispatcher`. The API is more awkward but it's more portable: `SynchronizationContext` works on all UI platforms. If you wrap `SynchronizationContext`, then you can use [`AsyncContext` for testing](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context).

If you do need an actual Dispatcher, though, then creating a Dispatcher instance is insufficient:

> Dispatcher.Thread is In STA mode (so it CAN handle GUI updates)

The thread is *marked* for STA, but part of actually being an STA thread is that it must have a message loop. So, you'd need an actual STA thread (i.e., one that does message pumping) for unit tests that queue to an STA. For testing in this scenario you should use something like [`WpfContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncCTPUtil/tree/master/AsyncTestUtilities).