# OnEvent datagrid column add fail

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid, dynamic-columns

I have a datagrid. I want to add columns as a result of an event.
So I do

```
 for (int iii = 1; iii <= 4; ++iii)
 {
  var dtgColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
  dtgColumn.Header = "AAA"
  Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { dtgResults.Columns.Add(dtgColumn); }));
 }
```

But despite using a dispatcher I get this error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Thank you for any help
Patrick
          }

Comment: Try use Application.Current.Dispatcher. for more details, see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher

Comment: Alas not working same as before

Comment: Where is dtgResults defined, and where is it instantiated? (which thread?)

Comment: There is a main thread which trough xaml defines the datagrid:  <DataGrid Name="dtgResults" Background="Transparent"/> then I run a thread command which resides in a library and when the finished event occurs I do add the new columns. So 1 main thread and one event from another thread.

Comment: try the "Application.Current.Dispatcher" instead of just Dispatcher. I think you're getting the wrong one somehow.

Comment: ВасилийШапенко already suggested it but it's not working. Would you elaborate what I'm getting wrong? Please not that if I put all that in a button and operate on the button click it works...

Comment: I also added AutoGenerateColumns="False" but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem not a `UI` control itself, but `dtgColumn`object created. You are creating `UI` element on one thread and add it to the `UI` element on the main thread.

Change your code like:

```
  Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { 
       var dtgColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
       dtgColumn.Header = "AAA"

       dtgResults.Columns.Add(dtgColumn); 
   }));
```

So the object is created and added on the thread that owns `UI` parent control.

Comment: The problem was related with the fact that I was calling that code in a function. So I added the Dispatcher to the function and it worked. So it's the same solution as yours.