# Task.Run not running in background but on Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I have one of my CPU intensive tasks blocking the UI thread, after investigating I've found that the root of the problem seems to be the Task.Run actually running in the Dispatcher thread:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        // breakpoint
    }
});
```

Placing a breakpoints in the if statement is hit.

Is this expected behaviour? I understood Task.Run to use a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action that you pass to `Task.Run` is executed on a thread pool thread if you use the default task scheduler (which you are by default).

This should give you the expected result:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        // breakpoint not hit in WPF...
    }
});
```

There is a difference between `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher` and `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`:

[Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher vs. Application.Current.Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448987/dispatcher-currentdispatcher-vs-application-current-dispatcher)

Comment: I knew I must have been doing something stupid. Thanks.

Comment: It is easy to accidentally type Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher by mistake with auto complete.