# Error when trying to remove item from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I want to add a `AppStateService`to my WPF application to display the state of the app and all things that are currently running in the background.

You can use it like that

`await appStateService.ExecuteWithStateAsync(new AppState("Loading order"), () => ...);`

The services executes the code and inserts/deletes the state text to an `ObservableCollection`

```
    public class AppStateService
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AppState> StateList { get; } = new();

        public async Task ExecuteWithStateAsync(AppState state, Func<Task> code)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => StateList.Add(state));            

            try
            {
                await code();
                state.StateType = AppState.Type.Finished;

                var deleteTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
                deleteTimer.Elapsed += (source, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => StateList.Remove(state));
                deleteTimer.Start();
            }
            catch
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => StateList.Remove(state));
                throw;
            }            
        }
    }
```

Looks quite simple, but I get an error "System.NotSupportedException" when deleteTimer.Elapsed.
"Von diesem CollectionView-Typ werden keine Änderungen der "SourceCollection" unterstützt, wenn diese nicht von einem Dispatcher-Thread aus erfolgen"

(This CollectionView type does not support changes to the SourceCollection unless they are made from a dispatcher thread.)

But to avoid this problem is why I run it with `CurrentDispatcher.Invoke`.
Where is my thinking error?

Comment: Is it possible that the collection view was created from another thread?

Comment: Do you mean that? `.AddSingleton<AppStateService>()`

Comment: The issue might be that since you are already in a background thread you are not accessing the right dispatcher. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10449345/12400637

Comment: Was exactly the issue. I mixed up `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`